# Aerosike AQL commands logging enable

Tags: aerospike, aql

How do we enable full aerospike db logging in terms of command level so that i got to know which aql commands are getting used by application?

Answer (score 3):

Please note if you're developing an application you should use the clients for C, Java, C#, Go, Python, Node.js, etc.  AQL is just a cli written using the C client for convenience when developing your data model. Regarding, logging, check Audit Trail under Security (Enterprise Edition only):  https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/security/access-control